# Prevailing law when land is impermanent?

Tags: united-states, australia

I live in an area where new land is developing from the slow deposition of soil at a river mouth.  As the land grows out of the water, it is covered for less and less time each day by the high-tide or by the river outflow, and some areas that were once never exposed are now well above the high-tide mark.

I believe, although I might be wrong, that in Australia the seabed is controlled by the Commonwealth no matter what state it borders. What is the status, in Australia, of the kind of newly developing land I have described ... and what approach prevails in other federated jurisdictions?

Comment: Why is this tagged united-states?

Comment: In Germany, such land is owned by the Bundesland by default and in the North Sea automatically part of the national park Wattenmeer

Comment: I tagged it United States because the United States is a union (federation) and hence the possibility at least exists that state vs federal law might be in similar conflict as in Australia. Indeed the only reason for marking it as Australia is that it just happens to be a place where I know that such a conflict does exists.

Comment: @Trish Perhaps you could explain further in an answer rather than a comment. What happens when the land becomes permanently above sea level? What about sea-bed land. Who controls these?

Comment: this has been asked and answered [In the past](https://law.stackexchange.com/a/52292/10334) - In Germany, such land is all formally land of the Nationalpark Watenmeer  (when in the north sea) and will be owned by the Bundesland till someone tries to buy it from them - and getting this land is very very hard. The legal process can take several years, and for the land that the railroad to Langeness created it was outright declared to never leave the Nationalpark, but the *right/obligation* to graze sheep was given to the people on Oland to *tend* this piece of *coast defense*

Comment: In the UK, if a physical boundary moves seaward (a process known as accretion or alluvion) as a result of natural causes which result in a gradual and imperceptible change the owners of the adjoining land will find that their property increases in size.  Landowners who find themselves in this situation may find their landholdings increase significantly and that valuable prescriptive rights are extended by simply sitting back and waiting for channels to silt up.